# ++ delante de variable adentro de un while - Lenguaje C

Tags: c, while, booleano, sintaxis

```
int bandera;
while (++bandera != 1) {
    bandera--;
}
```

No entiendo el código de `++bandera != 1`. ¿Significa que se le suma +1 a bandera y después se fija si es distinto a 1?

Comment: Como notas adicionales a la respuesta: en este código faltaría inicializar la variable, y más exactamente se fijaría en si es _distinto_ de 1.

Comment: Gracias, ahí modifiqué la publicación.

Answer (score 3):

Exactamente. El operador de pre-incremento, que es como se le llama, primero modifica la variable y luego la deja disponible para la expresión en la que se usa. El de post-incremento por el contrario primero usa el valor y luego incrementa la variable. En ambos casos el valor de la variable queda incrementado. Ocurre algo similar con los de pre y post decremento.

Una forma de verlo en funcionamiento sería:

```
int a = 0, b = 0;
printf(“pre: %d, post: %d\n”, ++a, b++);
printf(“a: %d, b: %d\n”, a, b);
```

El resultado es:

> pre: 1, post: 0

---

> a: 1, b: 1

Comment: Excelente respuesta! Más clara imposible, muchas gracias!